# Working of 64 bit drivers

Tags: 32bit-64bit, device-driver

I'm not a programmer, but learning some programming concepts.

My question is, on 32 and 64 bit systems, the HAL layer will be different as they are two different platform, how does the driver interact with HAL layer and in turn with CPU?

If we take an example of LAN driver, can anybody explain in high level what exactly happens in two different platform that is 32 and 64?

Any pointer will be great help...

Thanks,
Pramod.

Comment: Usually device drivers come in two versions, 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

You re-compile the drivers for each platform.   The APIs are the same but the code generated by the compiler will be different.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply... But i want to know more regarding memory management... Like when i check the IRQ and memory address in device manager for both 32 and 64 bit, they seems to be same.. for both 32 and 64 bit drivers.. How are the interrupts and memory range assigned to a device in the OS?

Comment: IRQs and other device resources have nothing to do with 64/32 bit.  This is handled by the operating system and the same algorithm are used for allocating resources.

Comment: Thanks man, that means that algorithm is essentially same for 32/64 bit Operating system when you consider windows 7 and it might change with the OS. By the way, where can i find that algorithm?

Comment: Try this blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/doronh/archive/2010/05/06/arbitration-and-translation-part-3.aspx

Comment: Is that same for both 32 and 64 bit windows? Like i'm doing an analysis of OS, on driver behaviour on both 32 bit and 64 bit platforms? I searched in many sites but they tell everything remains same,except some like pointer sizes,memory management etc.If i want to look into common aspects of both the drivers, what are the parameters from Operating system that i must consider to continue my analysis? Can you please help me on this...